# Tensorflow Object-detection running error

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to run object detection with faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco but it's giving an error. My computer is Windows 10. My TensorFlow version is 2.4.1 and my python version is 3.8.5 The code I want to run is :

```
python D:/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py
--model_dir=D:/tooth-detection/models/treatment/model
--pipeline_config_path=D:/tooth-detection/models/treatment/faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco.config
--num_train_steps=100000
--alsologtostderr
```

How can I fix the problem?
The error is :

```
    (base) C:\Users\canat\Desktop>--model_dir=D:/tooth-detection/models/treatment/model
'--model_dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(base) C:\Users\canat\Desktop>--pipeline_config_path=D:/tooth-detection/models/treatment/faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco.config
'--pipeline_config_path' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(base) C:\Users\canat\Desktop>--num_train_steps=100000
'--num_train_steps' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(base) C:\Users\canat\Desktop>--alsologtostderr
'--alsologtostderr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When I add config it's giving "'--pipeline_config_path' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." error what does it mean? I didn't find anything about it

Comment: Looks almost as if you tired to run not one but 5 commands. Are you sure there is no newline character before those `--<option>=...` tags? If you are not sure, copy the code you want to run into a single line in a text editor and then copy this line to the shell and try running it again

Comment: I took it from https://github.com/clemkoa/tooth-detection this repo. You can see on readme part. How can I run in one line? @jojo

Answer (score 0):

You should include a trailing backslash at the end of each line, if you have commands stretching out over multiple lines, so in your case, you can do this

```
python D:/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py \
--model_dir=D:/tooth-detection/models/treatment/model \
--pipeline_config_path=D:/tooth detection/models/treatment/faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco.config \
--num_train_steps=100000 \
--alsologtostderr
```

Another alternative is to make the entire command single line, and paste it in the terminal as mentioned by `jojo` in the first comment

Comment: The code returned the same error again. how can I write in one line?